# Implementing a simple nearest neighbours algorithm in R

Tags: r, nearest-neighbor

I am implementing a simple nearest neighbours algorithm, but want to first start off with a scaled-down toy example to see what could potentially go wrong and how to best fix problems.

Consider the following algorithm to compute the nearest neighbours `neigh` of a set of labelled observations `labs`:

```
labs <- LETTERS[1:4] # generate labels
vals <- runif(4) # generate distance values

df <- data.frame(labs, vals) # generate dataframe

df2 <- df[order(df[, 2], df[, 1]), ] # get nearest neighbours
df[,"neigh"] <- df2$labs # add nearest neighbours to dataframe

df
labs  vals      neigh
A     0.4195669     B
B     0.1872277     A
C     0.7873308     C
D     0.8513542     D
```

From the above, `df` simply outputs the nearest neighbour in `labs` based on a sorted vector of distance `vals`. Values that are close together in magnitude are considered nearest neighbours. `A`'s nearest neighbour is `B` since `0.4195669` is closest to `0.1872277`.

**However there is one problem**: both `C`'s and `D`'s nearest neighbours are themselves. In reality `C`'s should be `D` and `D`'s should be `C`. Why does this happen at all? Is there some behaviour of `order` that escapes me?

Comment: Ordering does not in any way produce nearest neighbors. It just orders the vector. So your code is incorrect. You have to compute the euclidean distance to determine nearest neighbours

Comment: `transform(df, neigh = labs[max.col(-\`diag<-\`(as.matrix(dist(vals)), Inf))])`

Comment: In the code you provide, you compute the euclidean distance matrix of the `vals`, convert the resulting object to a matrix and replace 0s occurring along the main diagonal with `Inf`. The nearest neighbour, `neigh`, for each `val` is then the maximum value of the columns. Why `max.col`?

Comment: The nearest neighbour is the one with the minimum distance. `max.cols` give the column that has the maximum value, Note that I am using `-` ie negative. So if i had `1,2,3,4` then to get the minimum `1` is the same as finding the maximum of the negative values

Comment: Thanks again. In my real problem, `vals` are already computed distances. Perhaps I should have made that clearer, but I still get the issue with the nearest neighbour of a given label being itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: Computed distance from what points? the val of lab A, what does it point to? Where/what is the distance from A-B? A-C? A-D? B-C? B-D? C-D? Vals cannot be the computed distance, unless you define the point it is computed from.

Comment: In my real problem, I use `split()` to get a list of labelled vectors, call it `lst`. Each vector in `lst` has a different length. I then do `lapply(lst, mean)` to calculate the mean distance within each vector of `lst`, call it `lst_mean`. From here, I do `lst[order(unlist(let_mean), decreasing = FALSE)]` to sort by increasing average distance and ensure the labels and sorted distances correspond to each other.

Comment: Then why are you trying to do nearest neighbour if you are using mean? Note that nearest neighbour uses distance of some sort. So for each label, you have distance to each other label. ie A-B,A-C,A-D then B-C,B-D etc. Not just one value as in your case

Comment: I suppose what I'm trying to do is a similar to nearest neighbours. My thinking is that from my last line of code in my last comment, i.e., `lst[order(...)]`, the "nearest neighobors could easily be read from the output, since everything is now sorted. For instance vector 1's nearest neighbour would be vector 2, vector 2's would be vector 3, and so forth.

Comment: Perhaps if questions remain, I will write another post using my real example

Comment: Sorting/ordering has no connection with nearest neighbours. Ie the between vals difference is not taken into consideration. Whatever you are thinking, it seems has no connection to nearest neighbours, since you are not using any distance. Nearest neighbours uses distances